# Servlet: doGet not returning

Tags: servlets

I receive an image in doPost method from a client application. I'm not supposed to store this image in any folder path, so i use the following code to store this image in session attribute as data byte.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fileName = null;
    fileName = request.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println("filename: " + fileName);

    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
     byte[] data = new byte[0];
     byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = din.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     // construct an array large enough to hold the data we currently have
     byte[] newData = new byte[data.length + bytesRead];
     // copy data that was previously read into newData
     System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
     // append new data from buffer into newData
     System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newData, data.length, bytesRead);
     // set data equal to newData in prep for next block of data
     data = newData;
     }      

     request.getSession().setAttribute("imageData", data);
}
```

I want to retrieve this from doGet method after its received. So, i am trying with the following doGet code to retrieve it.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    byte[] data = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("imageData");
    int len = data.length;
    byte[] imageData = new byte[len];

    for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        imageData[i] = data[i];
    }
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    response.getOutputStream().write(imageData);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

But, its NOT returning this image in doGet, when i call this servlet from an another client after some time.

Could someone please advise me, what I'm doing wrong here for not getting image in doGet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not supposed to store this image in any folder path, so i use the following code to store this image in **session attribute** as data byte.
>
> ...
>
> But, its NOT returning this image in doGet, when i call this servlet from **an other client** after some time.

Session attributes are associated with exactly one client, so one client can not get the session attributes from an other client

You could store the image in the servlet context, like:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("imageData", data);
```

Later, you can read the attribute from the servlet context.

Or, another possibility is to store the image in a static variable.

However, the image will be stored, although it is in memory. Maybe some Servlet Containers also store Servlet Context attributes on the hard disk.

Comment: Can you give an example to do that please

Comment: My requirement is like, each client should send specific images, not all clients will receive the same images.

Comment: I don't understand what your requirement is. Do you know about the [scopes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html) of the servlet specification?

Comment: I think my question is so simple. One servlet receives image from mobile client. Mobile client could be iOS app, Android app or windows phone app. I have a html web page, where these images are shared from servlet to html page.

Comment: @User817729 I think your question is not clear. Are the images shared between different clients, or does each client has its own images, which the others can not view?

Comment: second one you mentioned, "each client has its own images". But, please forget about those, i just want to know, how can we retrieve image from a servlet without storing it? STEP 1:- CLIENT 1 sends an image to servlet. STEP 2:- doPost gets this image. STEP 3:- Another client, CLIENT 2 will retrieve this image by calling this servlet (from doPost or  doGet) STEP 4: This is working fine, if  i store that image on the server side folder. But, I should not store this image, as this is very confidential image. In this case, how can it be retrieved from servlet.

Comment: My question is always, what should my approach, if i can't go with session attribute. You need to advise me, as i'm asking question. You said, scoped attribute, how can i do that? Any examples please?